# Android N call blocking numbers not getting

Tags: android, telephony

I am trying to get the call block numbers in android N, i want to know the given is block number or not (ex:- 5554 emulator number)

Contacts, sms, phone state permissions has been given to allow to access the block numbers and i followed the "Android Developer" site https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/BlockedNumberContract.html

But i am unable to get the block numbers, i am using latest android studio 2.2.2 and checked the functionality in android N emulator i don't have device.
Here is my code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

    // Button onclick method to show the logs

    public void displayBlockCursorCount(View view) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {

                String number = "5552";
            if    (BlockedNumberContract.canCurrentUserBlockNumbers(MainActivity.this)) {
                        if (BlockedNumberContract.isBlocked(MainActivity.this, number)) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "given number is blocked >>>>>> " + number);
                        }
                    }
              }
     }
}
```

I am getting the 
 java.lang.SecurityException: Caller must be system, default dialer or default SMS app.
Please post the comment if down comment and thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1):

To access blocked contacts,Your app should be default calling app or Messaging app else it throws security exception.

Answer (score 0):

Add additional check

```
 private boolean isAppAsDefaultDialer() {
    TelecomManager telecom = mContext.getSystemService(TelecomManager.class);

    if (getApplicationContext().getPackageName().equals(telecom.getDefaultDialerPackage())) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or check sources https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/providers/BlockedNumberProvider/+/android-7.0.0_r1/src/com/android/providers/blockednumber/BlockedNumberProvider.java

And make you app as defaul dialer

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="tel"/>
        </intent-filter>
```